# Is notifications height adjustable to any value?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I know the recommended `layout_height` for small notifications is `64dp`, but I want the notifications to be a little bigger (for example to be `128dp`). Is notifications height adjustable to any value or it has to be exactly `64dp` to make it look good on all devices without problems?

I use FCM to send notifications.

Comment: what do you mean by, "FCM notifications"

Comment: FCM stands for Firebase Cloud Messaging. I think there is no differences between FCM notifications and other notifications. but I don't know is notifications height adjustable to any value or it has to be exactly 64dp to make it look good on all devices without problems?

Comment: I know what FCM or notifications means. But I've heard "FCM notifications" for the first time. do you mean by "FCM notifications", the notification sent from firebase console's "cloud messaging" option??

Comment: @TouhidulIslam I've edited my post. I send notifications using postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the height of the collapsed notification layout is fixed at `64dp`, The only way to make it larger than that size is to make it **expandable** by using `NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle`. You can see the example [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html#image-style):

```
var notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_post)
    .setContentTitle(imageTitle)
    .setContentText(imageDescription)
    .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
            .bigPicture(myBitmap))
    .build()
```

However, according to [this source](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification), expanded notification layouts are limited to `256dp`. There is no way to exceed this amount.

Comment: You mean that I can set the height of the **collapsed** notification for example to `128dp` if I make it expandable?

Comment: Nope. Even if you make it expandable, the height of your collapsed notification will be `64dp`. You can only set the custom height for the **expanded** state. However, according to [this source](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification#create_a_fully_custom_notification_layout), it is not recommended as having custom height can cause layout compatibility issues on different devices.